# Read output from html hyperlink in sqlplus output in Oracle

Tags: html, oracle, hyperlink, href, sqlplus

I have a scenario, I need to grab output with SQL query (Oracle) and store result into a html file. When user will get html report, there will be a column which is hyperlinked. When user click on that hyperlink it will show an output stored on local machine. Below is my query. (There will be another query before it which will store results in Failed.txt file).

```
select max(start_time)database,total,sum(CASE when status='Completed' then 1 else 0 end) as Completed,'< a href=''file:///C:/Users/kaushal.dave/ht_test/failed.txt''>LInks</a>' Failed,
(select count(status) from t1_exp where status not in ('Completed','Failed')) as In_queue,server
from T1_EXP group by database,total,server;
```

Above, query executes well in database but when I see output, there is no hypelink of Failed.txt I can see. Attached screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIKfO.png)

Comment: try to use double quotes to enclose the file path:
select max(start_time)database,total,sum(CASE when status='Completed' then 1 else 0 end) as Completed,'<a href="file:///C:/Users/kaushal.dave/ht_test/failed.txt">LInks</a>' Failed,
(select count(status) from t1_exp where status not in ('Completed','Failed')) as In_queue,server
from T1_EXP group by database,total,server;

Comment: Hi Cyrille, I had already tried it but unfortunately no results.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that can help:

```
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON HEAD "<TITLE>List of courses</TITLE>"
COLUMN NAME HEADING 'Course Name'
COLUMN URLLINK HEADING 'Link'

SET ECHO OFF

SPOOL C:\LIST_OF_COURSES.HTML

SELECT ID, NAME, '< a href="||URL||">'||URL||'</a>' URLLINK
FROM COURSES;

SPOOL OFF

set MARKUP HTML OFF
```

That code was taken from [dba-oracle website](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_insert_hyperlink_into_oracle_output.htm)

Comment: Hi Gajendra, thanks I already used this code but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the query below, it worked on my machine, I removed the space before a opening tag.

```
select max(start_time)database,total,sum(CASE when status='Completed' then 1 else 0 end) as Completed,'<a href="'||'file:///C:/Users/kaushal.dave/ht_test/failed.txt'||'">'||'Link'||'</a>' Failed,
(select count(status) from t1_exp where status not in ('Completed','Failed')) as In_queue,server
from T1_EXP group by database,total,server;
```

Comment: Hi Sabe,Thanks a lot for checking on it. Unfortunately it still didn't worked for me.